# Nullability when converting generic Java callback to Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, language-interoperability

I'm trying to write a Kotlin wrapper on Spring's `TransactionTemplate`. The crucial code looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate

@Component
class MyTransactionHelper(
    platformTransactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager
) {
    private val transactionTemplate = TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);

    fun <T> inTransaction(block: () -> T): T {
        return transactionTemplate.execute(TransactionCallback<T> { block() })
    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile. This is because Java class `TransactionCallback`, defined in Java as:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TransactionCallback<T> {
    @Nullable
    T doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status);
}
```

is interpreted in Kotlin as returning nullable T - `T?`, but my `inTransaction` method returns `T`.

How can I change this code to make it compile, while at the same time allowing my callers to use a nullable type as the generic type?

I could do something like this:

```
fun <T: Any> inTransaction(block: () -> T): T = transactionTemplate.execute { block() }!!
```

but then my callers wouldn't be able to pass `block`s of type `()->Int?`.

Here's an example code, that I want to compile and run:

```
    val helper: MyTransactionHelper = TODO()

    helper.inTransaction {
        if (TODO("some irrelevant condition")) 42 else null
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible by any chance to create an `Intermediate` class that specifies a `@NonNull` attribute and then create the `wrapper` on top of the `Intermediate` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun <T : Any> inTransaction(block: () -> T?): T? {
    return transactionTemplate.execute(TransactionCallback<T> { block() })
}
```

(`: Any` bound optional). Note that thanks to variance, `() -> T` is a subtype of `() -> T?`, so users can pass a `() -> Int` (and still get `Int?` back).

However,

> The code doesn't compile. This is because Java class TransactionCallback, defined in Java as...
>
> is interpreted in Kotlin as returning nullable T - T?, but my inTransaction method returns T.

is not correct; the problem is `TransactionTemplate.execute` returning `T?`, not `TransactionCallback.doInTransaction`. And if `execute` is actually guaranteed not to return `null` when `block` doesn't (which I *think* is true from the documentation, but am not certain), then just add a cast to your original code:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> inTransaction(block: () -> T): T {
    return transactionTemplate.execute(TransactionCallback<T> { block() }) as T
}
```